# Issue with python lib

Tags: python, executable

when I try to exexcute my file, I obtain this error:

```
[20636] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIlOFEGz/libpython3.9.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIlOFEGz/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
```

I tryed different ways but I can't solve the problem.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: This should be a hint `version 'GLIBC_2.29' not found`